# Does someone with darkvision fools Nature's Mantle when the wearer is in a dim light area and thus stops it from granting its benefit?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items, vision-and-light

Looking at the rules in PHB p.183, it states that

> dim light creates a lightly obscured area.

But is the area still a dim light area if someone with darkvision has that area in its darkvision range?

I think that there is a difference between the actual area lighting and the observer's point of view of that area (darkvision considering dim light as bright light) but it is not that clear for me. Thus the question in the title as the requirements to grant the "hide as bonus action" is that the wearer be in a lightly obscured area.

thanks for helping out.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

#### Darkvision can prevent the function of Nature's Mantle.

[Nature's Mantle](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/natures-mantle) says:

> *While you are in an area that is lightly obscured*, you can Hide as a bonus action even if you are being directly observed.

So typically, when in dim light, you are lightly obscured. But, [Darkvision](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/monsters#Darkvision) says:

> A monster with darkvision can see in the dark within a specific radius. The monster can see in dim light within the radius as if it were bright light.

With respect to a creature with Darkvision, *you are not lightly obscured while in dim light*, as they can see in dim light as if it were bright light.

#### It becomes complicated when there are multiple observers with and without darkvision.

It gets weird when the Nature's Mantle wearer is being observed by a creature with, and a creature without darkvision.

With respect to the creature without, they are lightly obscured, but not with respect to the creature with. In this scenario, I would allow the bonus action hide, but it would not hide the wearer from the creature with darkvision, only the creature without it.

Comment: in the skulker feat for example, it states "you can Hide when lightly obscured".  This wording is clear that it is the observer that determines if you can or not.  In this case it says it is the area and even darkvision says "the monster can see IN dim light..." which does not change the area lighting but for the observer with darkvision.  wouldn't you think they would have written it the same way for nature's mantle using "when you are lightly obscured" instead of "when you are in an area of lightly obscured?  is there a text that suggests to interpret these two the same way?

Comment: @jonDraco I don't see a meaningful distinction between those two things.

Answer (score -1):

Darkvision doesn't affect how Nature's Mantle works. The only condition is "are you in an area that is lightly obscured?" Take Twilight Sanctuary for instance. Darkvision doesn't end Twilight Sanctuary, it still persists, just the creatures with darkvision can see into it, but that doesn't matter because you can take the hide action while being observed. If you were able to end Twilight sanctuary then they couldn't hide.